# How to view Insert/Update operations performed on Cosmos DB SQL API account on Diagnostic logs?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a NOSQL Cosmos DB API account and I want to see the Insert/Update operations performed on the account.

I have enabled diagnostic logs and using the **CDBQueryRuntimeStatistics** to get the details. It shows only the Query operations not all the operations in diagnostic logs.

Am I missing something here?

I am expecting this to show all the operations including Insert/Update as well

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong table in this case ,

as defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/cdbqueryruntimestatistics),

> This table details query operations executed against a SQL API
> account. By default, the query text and its parameters are obfuscated
> to avoid logging PII data with full text query logging available by
> request.

Instead, you should use the [CDBDataPlaneRequests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/cdbdataplanerequests)

> The DataPlaneRequests table captures every data plane operation for
> the Cosmos DB account. Data Plane requests are operations executed to
> create, update, delete or retrieve data within the account.

It should give the required information with all `Create/Upsert` Operations as well. Here are some of the sample [queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor-logs-basic-queries#resource-specific-queries)